# Screenshot with MediaProjectionManager and conversion to bitmap with wrong width

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an app that takes a screenshot of the screen using MediaProjectionManager, but I noticed that on some devices it adds black margins around the image. Instead of printing the screen normally.

Can anybody help me?

This is my code:

```
fun startCapture(resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data)
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
        displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels,
        android.graphics.PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2
    )
    virtualDisplay = mediaProjection?.createVirtualDisplay(
        VIRTUAL_NAME_DISPLAY,
        displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels,
        displayMetrics.densityDpi, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY or VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC,
        imageReader?.surface, null, null
    )
}

fun captureScreenshot(): Bitmap? {
    val image: Image? = imageReader?.acquireLatestImage()
    val bitmap: Bitmap? = image?.let { imageToBitmap(it) }
    image?.close()
    saveBitmap(bitmap)
    return bitmap
}

private fun imageToBitmap(image: Image): Bitmap? {
    val planes = image.planes
    val buffer = planes[0].buffer
    val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
    val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
    val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * displayMetrics.widthPixels

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        displayMetrics.widthPixels + rowPadding / pixelStride,
        displayMetrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by adding a new createBitmap.

```
private fun imageToBitmap(image: Image): Bitmap? {
    val planes = image.planes
    val buffer = planes[0].buffer
    val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
    val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
    val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * displayMetrics.widthPixels

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        displayMetrics.widthPixels + rowPadding / pixelStride,
        displayMetrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
        displayMetrics.widthPixels,
        displayMetrics.heightPixels)
}
```